# Qt not displaying PNG images on Linux

Tags: c++, windows, linux, qt, image

I have a software written using `Qt` which is meant to work on both Windows and Linux.

I use PNG images as icons for my `QAction`s, embedded in a resource.

I have the following tree directory:

```
/
  resources/
    icons.qrc
    image.png
```

Here is the content of `icons.qrc`:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/resources" lang="fr">
    <file alias="image.png">image.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

I declare my `QIcon` like that:

```
QIcon(":/resources/image.png")
```

Under Windows, it works well but on Linux (I only tried on Ubuntu 10.4 so far), the images aren't displayed.

Is there anything special I have to do for this to work ? Is this a configuration problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: isn't that extra slash at the beginning of /resources? maybe it can't find the file

Comment: @fabrizioM: I tried but unfortunately, it doesn't work. I even tried to link to the file directly.

Comment: Is Qt on linux comes with PNG files format support? Try for example BMP or JPG...

Comment: @mosg I tried with both jpg and bmp with no successful result :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I found out what was wrong.

It had nothing to do with being on Linux or Windows, it was due to the locale.

My linux system is in english while my Windows is in french. Since the resources had the `lang="fr"` flag, nothing was shown on non-french OSes...

A stupid mistake !

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it's all ok with you code.

Try to add this definition to your pro-file. I'm not really sure, but still we can try:

```
QTPLUGIN += qpng
```

and to your *mainwindow.cpp*

```
#include <QtPlugin>
Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(qpng)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Once I did that, the linking fails because he doesn't find "libqpng".

Comment: @mosg I tried with `.bmp` and `.jpg` as well, without result. Shouldn't it at least support these two ? I'll try to figure out with which options it was compiled.

Comment: @ereOn Did you tried to use absolute path to images (with different formats)? I mean with out using resources...

Comment: Also try to build your own Qt libs, from the sources... Or you did this to? Have a look also to the examples where using images... I remember one thing: on linux try: *QIcon("/resources/image.png")*, without ":" symbol...

Comment: @mosg I just compiled the last version from the sources but still no images are shown. Could it be a conflict with Qt3 ?!

Comment: I think Qt3 also supports images... I'll try to compile some Qt examples with images, today, on my OpenSuse 11.3 ... because just for now, I really don't know what is wrong with you code.

Comment: @mosg I finally found out, thank you for your help/your time.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

- In windows ==>  copy "imageformats" folder in Qt system folder to your EXE program folder.
- In linux ==> install libpng package.

then you will see the PNG image in your program.

In ubuntu, my program didn't display PNG image.
I installed libpng package (libpng16.* : sudo apt-get install libpng16*),
then my program displayed PNG image (toolbar button, splash window, and something).